# How do I navigate from a tab page to another tab page?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

What is the best way to navigate from a tab page 1 to another tab page 2?

The scenario is that I when I press a button in a tab page, it should navigate to another tab page. I can't set the main tab page's selected tab property because I'm in the tab page 1 viewmodel.

Here is my code, this isn't working but is what I intend to do.

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"{KnownNavigationParameters.SelectedTab}=TabPage2");
```

The working code is this, but the problem is that it reloads everything since it navigates to another instance of the MainTabbedPage then selects the TabPage2 tab.

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"MainTabbedPage?{KnownNavigationParameters.SelectedTab}=TabPage2");
```

Comment: Do you only have one tabbed page and you are using it twice?

Comment: I have a tabbed page with 2 pages inside. I want to navigate from the first page to the second page. But I want to navigate from the first page's viewmodel because the navigation will be triggered by an action in the viewmodel.

Comment: Do you want to navigate from one tab to another via code?

Comment: Yes, preferably from the tab's viewmodel.

Comment: Add your tabbed page code thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to tab use the following code, I am using this for navigating from a drawer and it works fine hope it will work for you.

```
var navParams = new NavigationParameters
{
    { "Title", "Page Title" }
};
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/{Tab Parent Page}/" + {Tab Page}, navParams );
```